# Namespace without roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, namespace, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I like to run a rosnode within a namespace but without roslaunch.
I have to find a problem related to a multi-robot scenario because I use name spaces to start rosnotes for each robot.
It looks like there is a problem with one node and I like to debug the node, so I like to start the node with a debugger but within a namespace.
Is this possible?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143796/namespace-without-roslaunch/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to set the [ROS_NAMESPACE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_NAMESPACE) environment variable to your namespace. Everything in the node should be pushed to the namespace.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-03-24**:
Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can remap ros names using rosrun without problems. The operator is := . E. g. when using image_view like

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw
```

you remap image -> /camera/image_raw. I think you can use this also to remap the namespace of your node without roslaunch.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-03-24**:
Thanks for the hint, but I like to debug the amcl node and I do not want to to remap all topics and I want to explore some problems occurring while using a name space.